# Глагол "висеть",как правильно сказать "Я (что делаю?)

Tags: глаголы

ГЛАГОЛ "ВИСЕТЬ".КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО СКАЗАТЬ: "Я (ЧТО ДЕЛАЮ?)

Comment: Переведите с английского языка на русский язык следующее предложение: "I am hanging under the ceiling".

Comment: Господи, Галактион, будьте милосердны! Человек не может образовать форму первого лица единственного числа, а тут еще с английского что-то переводить надо!

Comment: Не переводите предложение: "I am hanging under the ceiling instead of a lamp".

Comment: И долго Вы так висите? До 6-ти утра?.. 1) "Я вишу" 2) "Я висю под потолком вместо лампы"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вишу́ висе́л,висе́ла   —

Ты  виси́шь висе́л,висе́ла, виси́

Он,она,оно  виси́т, висе́л,висе́ла

Answer (score 1):

Информацию, которой Вас обеспечила Людмила, можно было бы беспрепятственно почерпнуть из любого словаря, содержащего формы слов, например из [этого](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_forms/7691/висеть).

Comment: Ответы на 80% вопросов  можно найти в том или ином словаре.

Comment: @ЛЕНЧИК, я, конечно, могу понять Ваше недоверчивое отношение к словарям, но в данном случае оснований для недоверия нет: целых n словарей подтверждают нормативность формы "вишу". Прошу прощения за нездоровый интерес, но зачем в таком случае Вам понадобилось еще одно подтверждение?

Comment: Понимаю, что вопрос детский, "киношный", задал его мой ребёнок, считаете ниже своего достоинства ответить, игнорируйте, опускать-то зачем?

Comment: Думаю, что наилучший вариант - это ответить на вопрос и указать источник, так как не все знают, какие существуют словари и как  быстро на них выйти. А вот найти ответы в словарях на 80% вопросов  довольно  затруднительно. Чаще всего словарь - это только дополнительное пособие.

Comment: @ЛЕНЧИК, Вас никто и не думал опускать. Я всего лишь ответила на вопрос, руководствуясь соображениями, высказанными Софией. Однако Ваш комментарий, отрицающий необходимость обращаться сюда с подобными вопросами, меня несколько озадачил.